# Prepend a command when entering commands

Tags: linux, command-line

This is a theoretical mind game bugging me.

If I would like to prepend commands like sudo and so on to commands being entered, an approach would be to set up aliases for specific commands.
But I was wondering if also a generic approach is possible, so now matter what I enter as command a specific command/string will be added to beginning of the command line.

Any ideas?

Comment: `alias foo='sudo foo'` will run `sudo foo` when you enter `foo`. It's a **really bad idea** because you can very easily break your system or irretrievably lose your data that way (I don't expect people to have backups anymore) but that's how you'd do it.

Comment: Cheers. That's the approach I already came up with, but it is a bit tedious if the list of commands is pretty long.
The prepended command would not be used for actions tampering with the system.
Sudo was maybe a bad example

Answer (score -1):

You might be interested in the `!!` history substitution, which substitutes `!!` with your last command.

```
$ apt update
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                           
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)                                      
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/                                                                         
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
$ sudo !!
[sudo] password for panki:
[...]
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
42 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

If this happens to you often, you might want to consider setting up an `alias`:

```
alias dangit='sudo !!'
```

Which makes this possible:

```
$ less /etc/shadow                                                                                                                                                                                       
/etc/shadow: Permission denied
$ dangit
<less opens the file>
```

Comment: Not exactrly what I was looking for, but this is a cool trick I will keep in mind  :)